# Regex to match letters and digits in a string optionally having a set of special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

https://regex101.com/r/RLi59p/1

```
/(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])([a-z0-9]+)[!@#$%^&*]*$/i
```

The regex I made matches following patterns:

- `Test2123`
- `568test`
- `test2rest`
- `@test2rest`
- `@test2rest@`

but it fails to match following patterns

- `@test2rest@5`
- `@test2rest@test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make little correction in your regex and define all allowed characters together in one like this,

```
(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])[a-z0-9!@#$%^&*]*$
```

In your regex, you have this,

```
([a-z0-9]+)[!@#$%^&*]*
```

which means in your input string, alphanumeric characters must come first and special characters at last, which is why it was failing.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `a-z` from your end of string check, so `@test2rest@#` matches but `@test2rest@a` does not.

Try:

```
/(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])([a-z0-9]+)[!@#$%^&*a-z]*$/i
```

Comment: this fails for a pattern like reset21@@1

Comment: @Satyaki yes, is that not what you want? `reset21@@1` was not in your list of examples.

Comment: true, I checked your solution with a dummy. Though, in my question I mentioned @test2rest@5